# How to add a row in SQL Server after Max Rank of a RANK() over partition by(T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe this is simple but I couldn't get it done:

I've got a table with monthly values. They're coming from NAVISION, so there are customers that have a contract and a monthly value for that contract. I transformed the data a little bit to have a starting point:

[image: DATA]

I wrote this query for retrieving the data:

```
with NEW_CTE as (

        SELECT  End_of_Month_Date,Customer_No,Monthly_Contract_Value
        , case 
            when customer_no<>lag(customer_No) over(order by customer_no,End_of_Month_Date) then NULL 
            else ISNULL(lag(Monthly_Contract_value) over(order by customer_no, End_of_Month_Date),0) 
            end as WertVormonat
        , case
            when customer_no<>lead(customer_No) over(order by customer_no,End_of_Month_Date) then NULL
            else ISNULL(lead(Monthly_Contract_value) over(order by customer_no, End_of_Month_Date),0) 
            end as WertFolgemonat
        ,rank() OVER(partition by Customer_No ORDER BY Customer_No,End_of_Month_Date) as RANKING
        FROM #contract_line)
```

What I try to get is a completely new line **after** the max rank for a customer, so in my Example after the ranking "24" I need a new row with the following data:

---

End of Month Date: should display the end of the next month **after** the max ranked month

Customer: Should display the same customer

Monthly Contract Value: 0

WertVormonat: Should show the contract-value from the pre-month

WertFolgemonat: Should show NULL

---

But that's not all. The row should only appear, if the date of the max ranked value is in the past. If the last Date is something like 01.01.2020 the additional row should not appear.

Very tricky - I know. If you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Thank you for your support guys!

Comment: Please define in SQL this logic as these are terms only you would know: *Should show the contract-value from the pre-month*. Also, does this temp table have a primary key?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case it means the new line should show the "Monthly_Contract_Value" of rank 24 (159.00). In the example above i realised this with the "lag" function

Comment: Since you already use WITH statement you can reuse the alias to make a union for real data and calculated one. Something like 
WITH NEW_CTE (...)
SELECT * FROM NEW_CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT  --- grouping data by customer, aggregate data and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the rows with a `select`:

```
select eomonth(dateadd(day, 1, end_of_month_date)),
       customer_no,
       . . .   -- your rules for the rest of the columns
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_no order by ranking desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and
      end_of_month_date < getdate();
```

You can put an `insert` before this to insert rows.  You can use `union all` to combine in a `select`.